# Two Separate Bouncing Arrows Using CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have two arrows "bouncing" in separate directions using CSS?

I have the following code on my site ([domainmarket.io](http://domainmarket.io)), which produces one bouncing arrow (which can be seen on the top left-hand corner), but I would like another arrow bouncing in another direction, but can't figure out how.

HTML

```
<div class="arrow bounce"></div>

<div class="topbarleft">
<a href="javascript:showhide('uniquename')">
<p><?php echo wp_kses_post( $ocin_topbar_text ); ?></p>
</a>

<div class="rightarrow bounceright"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
 @-webkit-keyframes  bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
    40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px);
    transform: translateX(-30px);
  }
    60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-15px);
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
    40% {
    transform: translateX(-30px);
  }
    60% {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
    40% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(-30px);
    transform: translateX(-30px);
  }
    60% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(-15px);
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}





@-webkit-keyframes  bounceright {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
    40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px)!important;
    transform: translateX(30px)!important;
  }
    60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(15px)!important;
    transform: translateX(15px)!important;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceright {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
    40% {
    transform: translateX(30px)!important;
  }
    60% {
    transform: translateX(15px)!important;
  }
}

@keyframes bounceright {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
    40% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(30px) !important;
    transform: translateX(30px)!important;
  }
    60% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(15px)!important;
    transform: translateX(15px)!important;
  }
}




.arrow {

  margin-top:0px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-image: url('http://domainmarket.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/arrow-1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.bounce {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}       

.bounceright {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}   

.rightarrow.bounceright {
    background-image: url('http://domainmarket.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/arrowright.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As you can see in my CSS code, I've tried to change the @keyframes to bounceright to see if that would work, but it hasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, you adding `!important` to the bounceright keyframes disabled them. Remove it and it works.

Declarations in @keyframes that are marked with !important are ignored. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#!important_in_a_keyframe

So here is the end result:

```
@keyframes bounceright {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
    40% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(30px);
    transform: translateX(30px)
  }
    60% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(15px);
    transform: translateX(15px);
  }
}
```

Edit: also, as the author of the question explained, change "bounce" with "bounceright" in the `.bounceright` CSS rule:

```
.bounceright {
  -webkit-animation: bounceright 2s infinite;
  animation: bounceright 2s infinite;
}
```

However, I found a much simpler solution to all of this: instead of using another arrow and another class, just use the same. So instead of:

```
<div class="rightarrow bounceright"></div>
```

use

```
<div class="reverse"><div class="arrow bounce"></div></div>
```

with the CSS rule:

```
.reverse {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  display:inline-block;
}
```

This way there is no duplication of the same code just to reverse the direction of the arrow.

Comment: I've tried to remove the !important clauses, and it still doesn't work with the other arrow.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out!

In the CSS file

```
.bounceright {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
```

SHOULD BE

```
.bounceright {
    -webkit-animation: bounceright 2s infinite;
  animation: bounceright 2s infinite;
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot to tell you about that. I just assumed that you changed it to bounce in the production site temporarily. You also removed the !importants, though, for it to work.